# Trace authentication redirects in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I'm looking for a tool that can trace authentication redirects in MVC. I've a complex view, with many partials views renders conditionaly. Some request redirects me at login view and I have to review manually every controller method to find the [Authorize] attribute. I tried F12 iexplorer tools, firebug extensions, firefinder, firequery, chrome extensions.... none of that covers exactly my requirement.

Any idea?, what are you favorite helpers for unobstrusive js and MVC development?

[7/10/2013]Edited
This is the class overwrite AuthorizeAttribute that I wrote following @mikalai tip.

```
public class LogableAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
     {
        String info = "AuthorizeCore";
        WriteToLog(info);
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        String info = "OnAuthorization " +
            filterContext.Controller.ToString() + "." +
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        WriteToLog(info);

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple class derived from AuthorizeAttribute which dumps its authorizationContext to log...

Comment: It maybe Works... I try follow your advise and I wrote a LogableAuthorizeAttribute overwritting AuthorizeCore, OnAuthorization and HandleUnauthorizedRequest. It trace log events, but not redirects. It only write a log after succeful authentication in login view. Am i doing some wrong maybe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @FranOtero - It would be easier if you described how your 'complex' view is built and how redirects occur, and what you'd like to see in log file.

Comment: My view is built using many partialViews with @HTML.RenderPartial method. I'd like register the name of the controller/action that redirects me to account/login. I'm using default membership provider with forms authentication. Overwriting AuthorizeAttribute writes "10:00:26 OnAuthorization Presentation.Web.MVCClient.Controllers.AccountController.Login", but I can't see which view causues this redirect.

Comment: RenderPartial shouldn't cause redirect, as far as I know. Html.RenderAction or Html.Action should.  Anyway - try to log only unsuccessful attempts in `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` override. So you'd get something like "Url: /some/action, Referrer: /main/action, Result: failed".

Comment: I have overrided HandleUnauthorizedRequest method but don't achive my target. I access at my home page, then it redirects me to login page and non of this methods write anything to log. Then I log in correctly and OnAuthorization write to log. Have you any simple code that you use? Thanks in advance,

Comment: @FranOtero  - still not sure what the exact problem is. Could you make the page code available somewhere?

Comment: I write a simple page to publish and your idea works perfectly with LogableAuthorizeAttribute. I 'll revise my real Project to try to find whats wrong. Thank you!